# Gradient and Hessian of $x x^T$ w.r.t. $x$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$,?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, hessian-matrix

> **Question:** 
>   Can we find the gradient and Hessian of $x x^T$ w.r.t. $x$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ ?

EDIT: 
If we can, may I know how to compute that? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, we can. ${}$

Comment: @Sobi You just made my day

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, do you really want the gradient of $x x^T$, which is an $n \times n$ matrix?

Comment: Yes, if it's possible.

Comment: My apologies, in that case the first comment is unjustified from my side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Gradient**
$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{Y}}{\partial x_i} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial y_{11}}{\partial x_i} & \frac{\partial y_{12}}{\partial x_i} & \cdots & \frac{\partial y_{1n}}{\partial x_i}\\
\frac{\partial y_{21}}{\partial x_i} & \frac{\partial y_{22}}{\partial x_i} & \cdots & \frac{\partial y_{2n}}{\partial x_i}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\frac{\partial y_{m1}}{\partial x_i} & \frac{\partial y_{m2}}{\partial x_i} & \cdots & \frac{\partial y_{mn}}{\partial x_i}\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Let $$\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{xx^T} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1^2 & x_1x_2 & \ldots & x_1x_n \\
x_1x_2 & x_2^2 & \ldots & x_2x_n \\
\ldots  &\ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
x_nx_1 & x_nx_2 & \ldots & x_n^2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
So $$\frac{\partial \mathbf{xx^T}}{\partial x_i} = \mathbf{Z}_i + \mathbf{Z}_i^T \qquad i \in \lbrace 1 \ldots x \rbrace$$
where $\mathbf{Z}_i$ is an all zero matrix except vector $x$ in its $i^{th}$ column.

**Hessian**

The derivative of $\frac{\partial \mathbf{Z}_i}{\partial x_j}$ is an all zero matrix except $1$ at its $(j,i)$ position. By symmetry, the derivative of $\frac{\partial \mathbf{Z}_i^T}{\partial x_j}$ is an all zero matrix except $1$ at its $(i,j)$ position. This means that 
$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{xx^T}}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} =  \mathbf{K}_{i,j} \qquad (i,j) \in \lbrace 1 \ldots x \rbrace$$
where $\mathbf{K}_{i,j}$ is an $n \times n$ matrix which is all-zero except at positions $(i,j)$ and $(j,i)$. Note that if $i = j$, we get a $2$ in the $i^{th}$ (or $j^{th}$) element.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! So, the gradient is actually $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{x} \otimes \mathbf{I} +  \mathbf{I} \otimes \mathbf{x}$, right? also could one say that Hessian is positive semidefinite?

Comment: you're most welcome. If you found the answer helpful, you can mark it as "correct" so that others will know it was helpful :) and what do you mean by $\otimes$ ? is it Kronecker product ? And Hessian is not necessarily PSD.

Comment: yes, I meant $\otimes$ as Kronecker product.

Comment: Btw, I think $i \in \{1,\cdots,x \}$ should be $i \in \{1,\cdots,n \}$, correct?

Answer (score 2):

It's a cinch to calculate these things in index notation.
$$\eqalign{
 F_{ij} &= x_ix_j \cr
G_{ijk} = \frac{\partial F_{ij}}{\partial x_k}
 &= x_i\delta_{jk} + x_j\delta_{ik} \cr
H_{ijkl} = \frac{\partial^2F_{ij}}{\partial x_k\partial x_l}
 &= \delta_{il}\delta_{jk} + \delta_{ik}\delta_{jl} \cr
}$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply, greg! this looks interesting... Is $\delta_{ij} = 1$ if $i=j$ else $\delta_{ij}=0$?

Comment: In your notation, Gradient and Hessian are 3rd and 4th order tensors, respectively? I must admit that I have difficulties in grasping tensors. :( . I hope someday I will be able to understand these tensors (I have learnt from you ..and learning continues.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard [Matrix differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus)

The gradient is $2x$ and the Hessian is $2 I$.

By the way I'm assuming you meant $x^T x$ since $x x^T$ is a matrix and don't have a gradient or Hessian.