# Gradient of $x \mapsto \log \left( \det \left( \dfrac {3}{10}I+xx^{T}\right) \right) $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, determinant, scalar-fields

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

$$f (x) := \log \left( \det \left( \dfrac {3}{10}I+xx^{T}\right) \right)$$

Calculate the gradient $\nabla f$.

---

I have been struggling to calculate $\nabla f$. My attempt is as follows.

$$\dfrac {df}{dx} = \left( \det \left( \dfrac {3}{10}I+xx^{T}\right) \right)^{-1} \cdot\dfrac {dg}{dx}$$

where $m : = \left(\dfrac {3}{10}I+xx^{T}\right)$

$$g := \det(m) =  \det \left( \dfrac {3}{10}I+xx^{T}\right)$$

$$ \dfrac {dg}{dx} = \det \left( \dfrac {3}{10}I+xx^{T}\right).Tr( \left( \dfrac {3}{10}I+xx^{T}\right)^{-1}.\dfrac {dm}{dx}) $$

$$\dfrac {dm}{dx} = \dfrac {d(xx^{T})}{dx}$$

is an $n \times n \times n$ tensor, and  $Tr(\dfrac {dm}{dx})= 2x$. So, I get

$$\dfrac {df}{dx} = Tr(\left( \dfrac {3}{10}I+xx^{T}\right)^{-1}.\dfrac {d(xx^{T})}{dx})$$

A second question is about checking this or other complex multivariate differentials, I know my attempts are wrong by using autograd in Python. It would be really helpful to know  if this is possible with SymPy or something similar, or it is rarely done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

$$f (\mathrm x) := \log \left( \det \left( \gamma \, \mathrm I_n + \mathrm x \mathrm x^\top \right) \right)$$

where $\gamma = \frac{3}{10}$. Using the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma),

$$\det \left( \gamma \, \mathrm I_n + \mathrm x \mathrm x^\top \right) = \cdots = \gamma^n \left( 1 +  \frac{1}{\gamma} \mathrm x^\top \mathrm x \right)$$

and, thus,

$$f (\mathrm x) = n \log (\gamma) + \log \left( 1 +  \frac{1}{\gamma} \mathrm x^\top \mathrm x \right)$$

Taking the partial derivative with respect to $x_i$,

$$\partial_{x_i} f (\mathrm x) = \frac{\frac{2}{\gamma} x_i}{1 +  \frac{1}{\gamma} \mathrm x^\top \mathrm x} = \left(\frac{2}{\gamma + \mathrm x^\top \mathrm x}\right) x_i$$

and, hence, the gradient of $f$ is

$$\nabla f (\mathrm x) = \color{blue}{\left(\frac{2}{\gamma + \mathrm x^\top \mathrm x}\right) \mathrm x}$$

Comment: This is also a nice approach. +1

Answer (score 6):

Let $M = \left( xx^T + 0.3I \right)$ and $f = \log \det \left( M \right)$.

We will utilize the following the identities

- Trace and Frobenius product relation $$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$ or $$A^T:B={\rm tr}(AB)$$
- Cyclic property of Trace/Frobenius product $$\eqalign{
  A:BC
   &= AC^T:B \cr
   &= B^TA:C \cr
   &= {\text etc.} \cr
  }$$
- Jacobi's formula (for nonsingular matrix $M$) in terms of differential  $$d\log \det \left( M \right) = d{\rm tr}\log\left( M \right) .$$

Now, we obtain the differential first and thereafter we obtain the gradient.

So, 
\begin{align}
df &= d \log \det \left( M \right) \\
   &= d \ {\rm tr}\left( \log\left( M \right) \right) \hspace{8mm} \text{note: utilized Jacobi's formula} \\   
   &= {\rm tr} \left( M^{-1} dM \right)  \\
   &= M^{-T} \ : \ dM \hspace{8mm} \text{note: utilized trace and Frobenius relation} \\
   &=M^{-1}\ : \ \left( dxx^T +  xdx^T\right)\\
   &= 2M^{-1}x \ : \ dx \\
\end{align}

So, the derivative of $f = \log \det \left( xx^T + 0.3I \right)$ with respect to $x$ is 
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f 
= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \log \det \left(  xx^T + 0.3I \right) 
=  2 \left(xx^T + 0.3I\right)^{-1} x  .\\
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks @user550103, so I have edited as I get to your step:  $= M^{-T} \ : \ dM$, but I do not understand how to work out the derivative of the outer product. Would it be possible for you to tell me what $\dfrac {d(xx^{T})}{dx})$ is and spell out the last step.

Comment: *two steps after  $= M^{-T} \ : \ dM$, I take it the last step is $2M^{-1}x \ : \ dx$ = $\sum _{ij}M_{ij}^{-1}x_{j}dx_{i} = df$

Comment: @JimSi The gradient $\frac{\partial xx^T}{\partial x}$ will be 3rd order tensor. So, I wouldn't go that direction. If you are interested then see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2911049/gradient-and-hessian-of-x-xt-w-r-t-x-where-x-in-mathbbrn-times-1

Comment: You could use Sherman–Morrison to simplify.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Sorry, I am not sure where I should apply Sherman-Morrison formula. Do you mean to the final gradient that involves perturbed/regularized rank 1 matrix inversion?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes, indeed, if I apply Sherman-Morrison formula, then apparently our answers are same.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo correct, because $M$ is symmetric.

Comment: @user550103, so with the last two steps, df = $M^{-1}\ : \ \left( dxx^T +  xdx^T\right)$, you are allowed to do that as not taking differential with respect to anything, then $df = M^{-1} \ : \ \left( dxx^T\right) + M^{-1} \ : \ \left( xdx^T\right) =  M^{-1}x \ : \ dx+ M^{-1} \ : \ \left( xdx^T\right)$

Comment: If that logic is correct above, I don't know how you reform the last summand on the right to $M^{-1}x \ : \ dx$, and thank you I'll have a look at the 3rd order tensor

Comment: @JimSi  $M$ is symmetric and so is $M^{-1}$. The reduction is allowed because transposition does not affect the value of the trace or the Frobenius product $\;A:B=A^T:B^T$